# how to draw Poly-line between two points by map-kit in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, mapkit

i have two points then how to draw Poly-line but Poly line is not coming 
and i declared like this in

.m file

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

    double currentLatitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"currentLatitude"];

     double currentLongitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"currentLatitude"];

    double shopLatitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"shopLatitude"];         
        double shopLongitude = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] doubleForKey:@"shopLongitude"];

           CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
        coordinateArray[0] = CLLocation Coordinate 2D Make(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        coordinateArray[1] = CLLocation Coordinate 2D Make(shopLatitude,shopLongitude);



        self.routeLine = [MK Poly line poly lineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
        [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1) Add `MKMapViewDelegate`

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
```

2) Set delegate

```
self.mapView.delegate = self;
```

3) Implement `viewForOverlay`

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 1.0;
    return polylineView;
}
```

Comment: thanks i forgot this line  self.mapView.delegate = self;  and how to get road poly-line in india

Comment: @SudheerKumar you have to send the coordinates to Google maps and get back the all the coordinates in array. and draw it in Map.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (MKPolyline *)polylineWithEncodedString:(NSString *)encodedString {
    const char *bytes = [encodedString UTF8String];
    NSUInteger length = [encodedString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSUInteger idx = 0;
    NSUInteger count = length / 4;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = calloc(count, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
    NSUInteger coordIdx = 0;
    float latitude = 0;
    float longitude = 0;
    while (idx < length) {
        char byte = 0;
        int res = 0;
        char shift = 0;
        do {
            byte = bytes[idx++] - 63;
            res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (byte >= 0x20);

        float deltaLat = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
        latitude += deltaLat;

        shift = 0;
        res = 0;

        do {
            byte = bytes[idx++] - 0x3F;
            res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (byte >= 0x20);

        float deltaLon = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
        longitude += deltaLon;

        float finalLat = latitude * 1E-5;
        float finalLon = longitude * 1E-5;

        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(finalLat, finalLon);
        coords[coordIdx++] = coord;

        if (coordIdx == count) {
            NSUInteger newCount = count + 10;
            coords = realloc(coords, newCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
            count = newCount;
        }
    }

    MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:coordIdx];
    free(coords);
    return polyline;
}
- (MKPolygonRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay {
  //  MKPolygonRenderer *polylineView = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    MKPolylineView *polylineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithPolyline:overlay];
    polylineView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
    polylineView.lineWidth = 4.0;
    [self zoomToPolyLine:mapview polyline:overlay animated:YES];
    return polylineView;
}
-(void)zoomToPolyLine: (MKMapView*)map polyline: (MKPolyline*)polyline animated: (BOOL)animated
{
    [map setVisibleMapRect:[polyline boundingMapRect] edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(25.0, 25.0, 25.0, 25.0) animated:animated];
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
   // NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;
    if (currentLocation != nil) {
      currlong  =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
       currlt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
    NSString *origin = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",currlt,@",",currlong];

    //I have just mention static location
    NSString *drivein = @"23.0472963,72.52757040000006";
    NSString *apikey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@",origin,drivein];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:apikey];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if(!error)
    {
        NSData *data = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                                       error:&error];
        NSArray *routesArray = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"routes"];
        NSLog(@"route array %@",routesArray);
        if ([routesArray count] > 0)
        {
            NSDictionary *routeDict = [routesArray objectAtIndex:0];
            NSDictionary *routeOverviewPolyline = [routeDict objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"];
            NSString *points = [routeOverviewPolyline objectForKey:@"points"];
            MKPolyline *line = [self polylineWithEncodedString:points];
            [mapview addOverlay:line];
        }
    }
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(currentLocation.coordinate, 500, 500);
    MKCoordinateRegion adjustedRegion = [mapview regionThatFits:viewRegion];
    [mapview setRegion:adjustedRegion animated:YES];
    mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;

    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = currentLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"Your current Locations";
    point.subtitle = @"You are here!";
    [mapview addAnnotation:point];
    [locationmanger stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```